# How to merge element-wise two RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Suppose I have two RDDs like

first

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

second

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

The new RDD would be

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

So, this is basically element wise merge...We assume that the two RDDs are of same size.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Spark's [zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#zip) function. As per doc:

```
>>> x = sc.parallelize(range(0,5))
>>> y = sc.parallelize(range(1000, 1005))
>>> x.zip(y).collect()
[(0, 1000), (1, 1001), (2, 1002), (3, 1003), (4, 1004)]
```

Be aware that this function assumes the same number of partitions and the same number of elements in both RDDs.